# Fixed sidebar pushed up by footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found dozens of questions regarding the fixed sidebar. My problem is that the sidebar shouldn't be fixed once the footer enter the viewport. You can see this exact same behavior on Gather.Ly or Trek Factory Racing page.

I assume their solution is simply kept the sidebar fixed, but rather pushed (margin-top) by number of footer pixels visible in the viewport.

My layout

100% wrapper with two divs. One for content and one with 100% height image. After the wrapper I have 100% width footer.

I guess my only possible solution will be jquery? Can you help me with the code? I seems to be little lost...

Comment: You need to provide us with some code in order for us to help you. Paste your code here (what you got now), and make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScrip to check whether the footer is in the viewport (the area you can see) or not. You can search for how to do that here on Stack Overflow, or use jQuery and this plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Your code could look similar to this (if you use the plugin I mentioned):

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
   if ( $('.footer:in-viewport').exists() ) {
      $('.sidebar').css('position','static');
   }
});

if (jQuery){
    jQuery.fn.exists = function() {
        return this.length>0;
    };
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you so much. This has actually worked. I have change your script by toggle classes rather than changing css directly. For my purposes it's actually much more elegant solution, no hard computing for margin offset required.

Comment: Glad I could help! Code on SO is always an suggestion, no fixed solution (well, at least often). Do whatever you prefer ;)